# Compilation error when publishing a ClickOnce application using MSBuild on CI server

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, report, clickonce

I have a windows form application and I'm trying to publish it using ClickOnce with MSbuild.

When I publish it locally, it works fine, but when I run the same script on my CI server it fails with this compilation error:

```
error rsInvalidReportDefinition: The report definition is not valid.  
Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' 
which cannot be upgraded.
```

Also, when I publish it using Visual Studio on the server, it works just fine... it's the msbuild call that fails.

My publish target is:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Publish" Properties="PublishDir=%(PublishDir.FullPath);Configuration=$(Configuration)"/>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.